# TVML - how to modify formTemplate to show "pin entry"

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml

TVML's formTemplate can easily be adapted to only allow numeric input:

```
<formTemplate>
  <textField keyboardType="numberPad">0000</textField>
  <footer>
    <button>
      <text>${TEXT("Submit")}</text>
    </button>
  </footer>
</formTemplate>
```

This gives a page like...

[image: numberPad]

I would like to reduce it even further to only display a "pin entry" screen as shown here:
[image: pinEntry]

Is this possible with TVML, without hosting an own UIControl? I have nowhere found any mentioning of changing styles like this. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the `divTemplate`. This allows support at least a few type (buttons, etc) but it is not documented what limitations there are.

Answer (score 1):

Use `secure` attribute in `textField`

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/TVJSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH42-SW37

```
  <textField keyboardType="numberPad" secure="true">0000</textField>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but this is not what I was looking for. Your hint helps to obfuscate the digits while typing (well, shortly after...) by changing them into dots. Same works with non-numeric keyboard, too, for passwords and such. I really am interested in second screenshot shown - that's a pin entry code page by other apps (non-TVML?).

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is the TVDigitEntryViewController. You can read more about it here:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/interface-elements/digit-entry-views/

TVDigitEntryViewController
A view controller that enables the user to enter digits, like a passcode, in your app.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvuikit/tvdigitentryviewcontroller