# How can a composite UITextField be created for a passcode in tvOS

Tags: swift, uitextfield, tvos, custom-keyboard

I am trying to create a simple way for users to set a 4-digit passcode in a tvOS app.  Currently I have used a UITextField and set a restriction on the allowed number of characters but I don't think it is very user friendly as a single field.

I have seen that tvOS App Store has a passcode feature where a user is presented 4 fields with the keyboard view.

[image]

How can a keyboard be created that shows 4 fields rather than a single in the inputview on tvOS?

Comment: Same question asked for TVML - no real results so far! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434312/tvml-how-to-modify-formtemplate-to-show-pin-entry

Answer (score 0):

As `UITextFields` conforms to `UITextInputTraits` protocol, it has a `keyboardType` property which you can use here:

```
    textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
```

Comment: Setting the keyboard type to .NumberPad will present only the numbers but there will also be a single field.  I am looking to split the field into 4 within the same InputView

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such component in UIKit. You can create it, using four one-digit `UITextFields` (maybe embedded in a `UIStackView`). You'll have to programatically move focus to the next text field after users enters a digit.

Comment: Hi Michal, I think that will work in iOS where the keyboard is presented under the fields but tvOS shows the keyboard with a single field in it's own view